# Is my Clojure function likely to be very slow with lists or vectors?

Tags: performance, data-structures, clojure

I’m just learning Clojure and I just wrote this function:

```
(defn replace-last [coll value]
    (assoc coll (dec (count coll)) value))
```

I’m just a little concerned that it’s likely to be really slow for either lists and/or vectors — I just don’t understand them enough yet to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For vectors, this will be pretty fast -- one of the promises of vectors is fast creation of slightly modified copies.

For lists, this won't work at all -- they are not associative (`clojure.lang.Associative`) and thus are not valid arguments to `assoc`. As for other possible approaches, if you need to get an actual list back (as opposed to a seq(able)), you're out of luck -- accessing / replacing the final element of a list is fundamentally a linear time operation. If, on the other hand, you'd be ok with a lazy seq which would look like your list except for the final element, you could implement a semi-lazy variant of `butlast` (the one in `clojure.core` is not lazy at all) and use that with `lazy-cat`:

```
(defn semi-lazy-butlast [s]
  (cond (empty? s) s
        (empty? (next s)) nil ; or perhaps ()
        :else (lazy-seq (cons (first s)
                              (semi-lazy-butlast (next s))))))

(defn replace-last [s x]
  (if (empty? s) ; do nothing if there is no last element to replace
    s
    (lazy-cat (semi-lazy-butlast s) [x])))
```

This defers replacing the final element until you actually get close to it in consuming your seq.

A sample interaction:

```
user=> (take 10 (replace-last (range) :foo))
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
user=> (take 10 (replace-last (range 10) :foo))
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 :foo)
user=> (replace-last () :foo)
()
```

Comment: I think `butlast` should be considered deprecated. `clojure.core` also contains `drop-last`, which, apart from being lazy, has the advantage of being able to drop any amount of elements off a seq, not just one.

Comment: @DanielJanus: Wow, I totally missed `drop-last`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will be as fast as anything else for vectors, and won't work at all for lists.